# Is there a way in PyTest to pass command line arguments to conftest.py directly?

Tags: python, pytest

I know that there is a way to pass args in tests itself [like it was shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42145604), but is there a way to pass in conftest.py directly? I want to configure some common stuff for all tests this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like this:

File: conftest.py

```
option = None

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--arg", action="store", default="example", help="Option for making some stuff")

def pytest_configure(config):
    global option
    option = config.option
```

and you can access your argument with `option.arg` in your conftest file.